# Modify Local Variables Inside Kotlin Lambdas

Tags: android, kotlin

From what I already know:
When function call completes all the local variables inside it get destroyed.

**Question is**: How come in the below code snippet a lambda can change the value of a local variable (color variable)? 
The lambda runs when an event occurs on RadioGroup and when that happens the `showDialog()` function has run to end.

```
fun init() {
  var color = 0
  rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
    val childCount = group.childCount
    for (index in 0 until childCount) {
      val button = group.getChildAt(index)
      if (button.id == checkedId) {
        color = index
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android Studio you can use Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode, and then Decompile to see what the corresponding Java code might look like.

You'll then see that `color` actually turns into a `final IntRef color = new IntRef();`, where `IntRef` is a class in the Kotlin runtime that has a public `int element` member holding the actual value.

Since `color` is a `final` reference to an object, your `OnCheckedChangeListener` can capture it just fine. The member `int` is not `final` however, which is why you can assign to it (the compiler turns your `color = index` into `color.element = index;`).

Answer (score 0):

It's changed internally to a single element array reference.

Think of it like this:

```
fun init() {
  var color = arrayOf()
  color[0] = 0
  rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
    val childCount = group.childCount
    for (index in 0 until childCount) {
      val button = group.getChildAt(index)
      if (button.id == checkedId) {
        color[0] = index
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That's how it can be accessed after the fact.

Comment: It isn't an array, it's a special class, as Michael's answer says. The array thing is a reasonable way to write it in Java where you don't have such a class in the standard library and can only capture `final` variables.

Comment: Well there you go :-) same idea