# Kotlin : why my forEach / for loop stops during first iteration just after setEnabled()

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to update the UI in a forEach loop but the program exits the loop during the first iteration just after calling setEnabled() on a button.

```
private var prod1Allowed = false
private var prod2Allowed = false


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 //...
 startConnection()
 //...
}

// Manages connection to Google Billing API
fun startConnection(){

 billingClient().queryPurchasesAsync(
                    BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP
                ) { billingResult, productList ->
                    
                    Log.d(TAG, "The ${productList.size} owned products are ${productList.map { it.skus }}"
                    )

                    productList.forEach {
                        Log.d(
                            TAG,
                            "Current product is ${it.skus}"
                        )
                        if (it.skus.contains(PROD_1)) {
                            prod1Allowed = true
                            binding.prod1Button.setEnabled(true)

                            Log.d(TAG, "Prod 1 is allowed") // from here on not shown
                        }
                         if (it.skus.contains(PROD_2)) {
                            prod2Allowed = true
                            binding.prod2Button.setEnabled(true)
                            Log.d(TAG, "Prod 2 is allowed")
                        }
                    }

  }

 }
```

Which outputs :

> The 2 owned products are [[prod_1], [prod_2]]

> Current product is [prod_1]

I also tried with a `for (it in productList)` but the loop also exited at the same location.

If I don't do the `setEnabled` I can see that the next element is iterated.

There is no warning from Android studio (no exception either at runtime and no null pointer exception regarding binding which is initialized) and [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60486499/6351897) explains that it is possible to change a variable defined outside of the lambda.

So the `setEnabled()` call seems to prevent my loop not to flow as it should be, but there is no error at runtime. What can be done ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: i'm not sure what the it.skus.contains is doing, but is there a possibility that it can get stuck in there (something like an infinite loop)? Since the logs in the ifs are not showing, there's a chance that it might be the case.

Comment: Maybe because `queryPurchasesAsync`'s callback executes on separete thread and you trying to modify view?

Comment: Yes, my guess is that `setEnabled()` throws an exception due to wrong thread and then this async util, whatever it is, just consumes this exception silently. Just put your `forEach()` in a try-catch to verify this.

Comment: Good catch, thanks to you three. Now with the `try-catch` the exception clearly appears : `There is a problem android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads`. I will try to mitigate this. But how comes that the exception is silently consumed, is it a feature of Kotlin ?

Comment: Enclosing the `setEnabled` within `runOnUIThread` solved the problem : `runOnUiThread {                 Log.d(TAG, "Modifying the prod1 button view on the UI Thread" )                 binding.prod1Button.setEnabled(true)             }` But your point is interesting to wrap the problem in try-catch block.Would you mind elaborating in an answer why it is consumed and what could be done to spot the problem at runtime so that I can accept your solution ?